# Analyzing XML that has unknown schema

Tags: java, xml

I have a big XML file but I do not know its schema. I can go through all the elements but it will take time and I may make mistake. I can write a code to analyze it but before I do, **I would like to know if there is anything out there that can be used to analyze the XML files**? Preferably, stand alone or Java libraries.

The information I would like to know are, for example, what are all the XML tags in the file, what elements and attributes may each tag contain, etc. These are important for me to make sure that the XML processor that I will write will not miss out any entry in the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some schema generation tools can be quite useful for you. Here are some of them:

1. [XML Schema Definition Tool from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28VS.80%29.aspx)
2. [inst2xsd from XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/tools.html#inst2xsd)
3. [Trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't ever know that unless you have all the xml files you could ever possibly get. Me I'd use a tool to build an xsd from a file, and then code against that. I'd validate each file against it, when there was a problem, square the xsd,  use the value as required and gradually build up a picture of what the xsd should have been as I got more and more candidate files. It's possible there isn't one you know, could end up a horrific pile of choice elements and you might have to start categorising it.

Comment: that one file is all the XML i need.